# Using Impersonation in ASP.NET Using .NET Framework 4.6.1 Hosting in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, impersonation

I'm trying to create a website that uses Windows Authentication and impersonation, however it is not working.  It doesn't look like impersonation is doing anything.

I tried using Http.sys instead of Kestrel, but [according to MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.0) this isn't supported.  Is this possible?

This is what the impersonation code in my controller looks like:

```
        var user = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, () =>
        {
             // Do something as impersonated user
        });
```

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? Please revise your question.

Comment: Its asp.net-core 2.0 using the full .NET Framework (as opposed to .NET Core)